# OpenCV decision tree parameters issue

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

I am using a decision tree for 16 class problem. I set the parameters to

```
CvDTreeParams params = CvDTreeParams(50, // max depth
    100,// min sample count
    0, // regression accuracy: N/A here
    true, // compute surrogate split, no missing data
    16, // max number of categories (use sub-optimal algorithm for larger numbers)
    5, // the number of cross-validation folds
    false, // use 1SE rule => smaller tree
    false, // throw away the pruned tree branches
    priors // the array of priors
);
CvDTree* dtree = new CvDTree();
dtree->train(data, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, classes,
    Mat(), Mat(), var_type, Mat(), params);
```

but the resulting tree is giving only 25 depth max. It is not increasing the depth. I tried the same data on Matlab and the tree depth is 50. Is there anything limitng the tree depth in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is hard limit of 25 for max depth in the OpenCV source code. So have to change binaries to make it work.